# Reading and splitting a .csv file, which contains strings with commas in

Tags: python, string, csv, split

I have a .csv file which looks something like this:

```
1,2,"a,b",3
4,"c,d",5,6
```

Which I am reading and storing in an array like this:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
data = [line.split(',') for line in data]
```

Which results in an array like this:

```
[['1','2','"a','b"','3']['4','"c','d"','5','6']]
```

HOWEVER, I would like to keep the items within double quotes such as "a,b" in one element of the  data array (which is how they are opened in Excel), like this:

```
[[1,2,'a,b',3][4,'c,d',5,6]]
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this in Python?

Edit: preferably without using the csv module if possible?

Comment: You can use the module `csv`

Comment: Or you can implement your own parser as well

Comment: @dcg I was trying to avoid using that to keep things clean and simple, but if that's the only way...

Comment: I think is simpler using `csv` than having to do it by yourself

Comment: Using the `csv` module, that is part of the standard library, is really the best choice here. It's simple to use (see my answer using it below), and you can be sure that all possible problems like this one, quoting and so on have been correctly solved and that you won't encounter a bug in some corner case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `csv` module:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', 'a,b', '3']
['4', 'c,d', '5', '6']
```

Or, if you don't want to read lines lazily and want all in a single list, as in your question, you can simply do:

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)

print(data)        
# [['1', '2', 'a,b', '3'], ['4', 'c,d', '5', '6']]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `csv` module:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    
data = [row for row in reader]
```